# recursion not navigating all child nodes

Tags: java, recursion, 2-3-tree

I need to navigate my 23Tree and print all the levels and corresponding elements. However, my recursion goes in any one direction and does not return and perform other calls. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my node class:

```
class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    List<T> vals = new ArrayList<T>();
    List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();

    boolean isLeaf() { return children.size() == 0; }
    boolean is4Node() { return vals.size() == 3; }

    // new Nodes always are 2-nodes (1 value).  The node may be
    // a leaf, or has 2 children.
    Node(T x) {
        vals.add(x);
    }

    Node(T x, Node<T> left, Node<T> right) {
        vals.add(x);
        children.add(left);
        children.add(right);
        children.add(null); // hack
    }
```

This is my recursive function to print the nodes:

```
private boolean iterateChildrenAndPrintPerLevelAndLevelType(int level, String levelType,  Node root){
    System.out.println("present element: " + root);
    if(root.vals.size() == 1 ){
        System.out.println("Level = " + level + " [" + levelType + "] value = " + root.vals.get(0));
    }else if(root.vals.size() == 2 ){
        System.out.println("Level = " + level + " [" + levelType + "] value = " + root.vals.get(0) + "/" + root.vals.get(1));
    }

    if(root.children.get(0) != null){
        iterateChildrenAndPrintPerLevelAndLevelType(level+1, "left", (Node) root.children.get(0));
    }
    if(root.children.get(1) != null){
        iterateChildrenAndPrintPerLevelAndLevelType(level+1, "middle", (Node) root.children.get(1));
    }
    if(root.children.get(2) != null){
        iterateChildrenAndPrintPerLevelAndLevelType(level+1, "right", (Node) root.children.get(2));
    }
    return true;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
present element: [[[a]b[c]]d, [[e]f[g]]h[[i]j, [k]y[z]]]
Level = 0 [root] value = d/h
present element: [[a]b[c]]
Level = 1 [left] value = b
present element: [a]
Level = 2 [left] value = a
```

(Edit) Here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringTwoThreeTree set = new StringTwoThreeTree();
    try{
        String line = null;
        FileReader fileReader =
                new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Redoubt\\IdeaProjects\\23Tree\\src\\resources\\test.dat");
                // new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Redoubt\\IdeaProjects\\23Tree\\src\\resources\\a4q1search.txt");

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            set.insert(line);
        }
        // System.out.println("\n\n\n");
        String str = set.toString();
        // System.out.println(str);
        set.print();
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

and the contents of the file test.dat :

```
a
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
y
z
```

Just for clarity, I'm adding the 2 large classes as well:
StringTwoThree class:

```
import java.util.List;

public class StringTwoThreeTree extends TwoThreeTree<String> {

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString();
}

public void insert(String str){
    super.add(str);
}

public void print(){
    Node root = super.root;
    // System.out.println(root.vals);
    // dumpList("",root);
    iterateChildrenAndPrintPerLevelAndLevelType(0, "root", root);


    super.displayLevelWise();
}

private void dumpList(String string, Node list) {
    int i = 0;
    for (Object item : list.children) {
        if (item instanceof List) {
            dumpList(string + i, (Node) item);
        } else {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s%d %s", string, i, item));
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

private boolean iterateChildrenAndPrintPerLevelAndLevelType(int level, String levelType,  Node root){
    System.out.println("present element: " + root);
    if(root.vals.size() == 1 ){
        System.out.println("Level = " + level + " [" + levelType + "] value = " + root.vals.get(0));
    }else if(root.vals.size() == 2 ){
        System.out.println("Level = " + level + " [" + levelType + "] value = " + root.vals.get(0) + "/" + root.vals.get(1));
    }

    if(root.children.get(0) != null){
        iterateChildrenAndPrintPerLevelAndLevelType(level+1, "left", (Node) root.children.get(0));
    }
    if(root.children.get(1) != null){
        iterateChildrenAndPrintPerLevelAndLevelType(level+1, "middle", (Node) root.children.get(1));
    }
    if(root.children.get(2) != null){
        iterateChildrenAndPrintPerLevelAndLevelType(level+1, "right", (Node) root.children.get(2));
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

TwoThreeTree class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Queue;

public class TwoThreeTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {

// a Node has 1 (2-Node) or 2 (3-Node) values
// and 2 or 3 children.  Values and children are stored
// in ArrayLists.  If there are children, that ArrayList
// has a null element at the end, so as to make easier the
// method which adds a new child.
class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    List<T> vals = new ArrayList<T>();
    List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();

    boolean isLeaf() { return children.size() == 0; }
    boolean is4Node() { return vals.size() == 3; }

    // new Nodes always are 2-nodes (1 value).  The node may be
    // a leaf, or has 2 children.
    Node(T x) {
        vals.add(x);
    }

    Node(T x, Node<T> left, Node<T> right) {
        vals.add(x);
        children.add(left);
        children.add(right);
        children.add(null); // hack
    }

    public String toString() {
        String answer = "[";
        for (int i=0; i<vals.size(); i++) {
            if (i != 0) answer += ", ";
            if (children.size() != 0)
                answer += children.get(i).toString();
            answer += vals.get(i);
        }
        if (children.size() != 0)
            answer += children.get(children.size()-2).toString();
        return answer + "]";
    }

    // used in Iterator
    void getVals(List<T> iteratorList) {
        for (int i=0; i<vals.size(); i++) {
            if (children.size() != 0)
                children.get(i).getVals(iteratorList);
            iteratorList.add(vals.get(i));
        }
        if (children.size() != 0)
            children.get(children.size()-2).getVals(iteratorList);
    }

    // recursively adds a new value to a subtree
    boolean add(T val) {
        if (isLeaf())
            return addToLeaf(val);
        else return addToInterior(val);
    }

    // new values are always added to a leaf.  The result may be a 4-node leaf.
    boolean addToLeaf(T x) {
        int cmp;
        // size is 1 for a 2-node, or 2 for a 3-node
        for (int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++) {
            cmp = x.compareTo(vals.get(i));
            if (cmp == 0) return false;
            else if (cmp < 0) {
                vals.add(i,x);
                return true;
            }
        }
        vals.add(x);
        return true;
    }

    // adds a value to a subtree rooted by an interior node.  If
    // the addition results in one of the children being a 4-node,
    // then adjustments are made.
    boolean addToInterior(T x) {
        int cmp;
        // size is 1 for a 2-node, or 2 for a 3-node
        for (int i = 0; i <= vals.size(); i++) {
            if (i == vals.size()) cmp = -1; // hack because there is no vals[2]
            else cmp = x.compareTo(vals.get(i));
            if (cmp == 0) return false;
            else if (cmp < 0) {
                boolean retVal = children.get(i).add(x);
                if (children.get(i).is4Node())
                    childIs4Node(i);
                return retVal;
            }
        }
        return false;  // unreachable  -- just for compiler
    }

    // the ith child is a 4-node
    void childIs4Node(int i) {
        Node<T> the4Node = children.get(i);
        // move the middle value from the 4-node child up
        // to its parent
        if (i == 2)
            vals.add(children.get(i).vals.get(1));
        else vals.add(i, children.get(i).vals.get(1));
        Node<T> newChild1, newChild2;
        if (children.get(i).isLeaf()) {
            newChild1 = new Node<T>(children.get(i).vals.get(0));
            newChild2 = new Node<T>(children.get(i).vals.get(2));
        }
        else {
            newChild1 = new Node<T>(children.get(i).vals.get(0),
                    children.get(i).children.get(0),
                    children.get(i).children.get(1));
            newChild2 = new Node<T>(children.get(i).vals.get(2),
                    children.get(i).children.get(2),
                    children.get(i).children.get(3));
        }
        children.remove(the4Node);
        children.add(i, newChild2);
        children.add(i, newChild1);
    }
}

Node<T> root;

public TwoThreeTree() {
    root = null;
}

// TwoThreeTree add
public boolean add(T val) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node<T>(val);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        boolean isNew = root.add(val);
        // if root is a 4-node, split it
        if (root.vals.size() == 3) {
            Node<T> left, right;
            if (root.isLeaf()) {
                left = new Node<T>(root.vals.get(0));
                right = new Node<T>(root.vals.get(2));
            }
            else {
                left = new Node<T>(root.vals.get(0),
                        root.children.get(0),
                        root.children.get(1));
                right = new Node<T>(root.vals.get(2),
                        root.children.get(2),
                        root.children.get(3));
            }
            root = new Node<T>(root.vals.get(1), left, right);
        }
        return isNew;
    }
}

// this method creates a list containing all of the values in
// the tree and returns that list's iterator
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    List<T> vals = new ArrayList<T>();
    if (root != null) root.getVals(vals);
    return vals.iterator();
}

public String toString(){
    String result = "[";
    for (T item : this
         ) {
        result += item.toString() + ",";
    }
    result = result.substring(0,result.length()-1);
    result += "]";
    return result;
}

public void displayLevelWise(){

}

}
```

Comment: please include your main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index is going out of bound in your `private boolean iterateChildrenAndPrintPerLevelAndLevelType(int level, String levelType,  Node root)` method.